# Equivalent definition of residually finite group

Tags: group-theory, c-star-algebras

I'm reading this paper that deals with group $C^*$-algebras and the definition of a residually finite group is if it has a separating family of finite index normal subgroups.  I've seen many of the equivalent definitions online but none of them to be phrased in terms of a separating family, and I cannot seem to find a definition of that either.

Comment: I would assume (from reading the wiki page) this means that $G$ is residually finite if there is a family $\{H_\alpha\}$ of normal subgroups of $G$ of finite index such that $\cap_\alpha H_\alpha$ is the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Yeah but I want to know what it means in terms of the papers definition because I believe that's what he uses to prove things.

Comment: Well Aweygan seems to have answered that question, so I am unclear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I understand all of the definitions on wikipedia, I wanted to know why they're the same as the one I gave above, specifically because I didn't know the precise definition of a separating family.  In any event it just means there's enough finite index normal subgroups so that for any two points in the group, you can take one of your subgroups and the points are sent to different cosets, which in turn comes out to be equivalent to the definition of Aweygan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every group $G$ may be made into a topological group by taking as a basis of open neighborhoods of the identity, the collection of *all normal subgroups of finite index in $G$*. The resulting topology is called the *profinite* topology on $G$. A group is residually finite if, and only if, its profinite topology is Hausdorff. So any two points can be "separated" by disjoint open neighborhoods.